# Discontinuous boundary condition in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

Assume we have any PDE to be solved on the rectangular domain $0<X<4$ and $0<y<2$ How do we tell *Mathematica* to impose the following boundary conditions?

$\cases{
U[0,y,t]=0,& if $0<y<1$,\cr
U[0,y,t]=1,& if $1<y<2$,\cr}$

$U[x,2,t]=1$

and zero for the rest of the boundary.

I have the following code which runs but does not return a result:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == (1/500)*(D[u[x, y, t], x, x]+D[u[x, y, t], y, y]),
    u[x, y, 0] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0,x==0 && 0 <= y <= 1], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 1, x == 0 && 1 <= y <= 2], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, x == 4],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t]==1, y == 2],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 1, y == 0]}, 
    u, {x, 0, 4}, {y,0, 2}, {t, 0, 2000}]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see the warning

```
NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.
```

This may indicate the `NDSolve` did try to solve this as a purely spatial problem. You can force it so use the `MethodOfLines` via the option `Method -> "MethodOfLines"` for time integration. This then solves in seconds.

```
s = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y, t], 
    t] == (1/500)*(D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]), 
  u[x, y, 0] == 0, 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, x == 0 && 0 <= y <= 1], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 1, x == 0 && 1 <= y <= 2], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, x == 4], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 1, y == 2], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 1, y == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 
  2}, {t, 0, 2000}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"]
```

Plotting the solution at `t=2000`:

```
Plot3D[u[x, y, 2000] /. s, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, u}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question produces results, but running to `t = 2000` takes a while.  Here is the result for `t = 100`, which took about seven minutes on my computer.  Running to `t = 2000` could take a few hours, and at some point memory usage could become an issue.

```
Plot3D[u[x, y, 100] /. s, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, u}]
```

[image]

Note that `NDSolve` gives the warning,

```
NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help. >>
```

Although no instability is obvious in the plot, one might develop at later time.  Note, also, that discontinuities in the boundary conditions may not be well resolved on the grid.  However, improving resolution will increase run time.